# SQL, row values mysteriously being overwritten by other values in the column the value is in

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL odd error that is kind of hard to explain. It seems to most likely be an SQL problem anyway.

I have a MYSQL table with forum posts in it, and values in rows are being overwritten somehow with other values. The entire row is not being overwritten, which is what would happen if someone made a new post, or edited a post. Which is why I'm confused by it. I've ruled out that it couldn't be the person editing their post because one of them was my posts, and it was over written by a different message that I didn't write, however it has the title I did write.

Another reason I'm sure this is not just people editing posts is I have an edit history table, and these changes are not in that table.

I did however import many of the posts, so they have imported ID's in the auto-incrementing index of the table. I'm not sure if that would cause the issue.

This is originally made forum software by me, so I can't do something like go ask VB, or other forum developers about it.

I greatly appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: Very blurry question I gotta say - post some code at least. You think it's an SQL problem - how so? Are you using triggers or something?
Post the code, where you insert/update the table in question.

Comment: At the time it would have been capable of being from many different SQL queries which is why I was hesitant on posting code. I was looking for any advice someone can give on the vague issue. I found out what it was though, there was an error that happened while converting old posts into the new database.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely suspect is an `UPDATE` statement which has a "wrong" predicate. (Either a missing predicate or a wrong predicate...  `id_column = wrong_value`, or `wrong_column = id_value`.  Also suspect would be an "order of precedence" issue, with the evaluation of an `OR` condition (i.e. missing parens).

Or, there might be a a problem in the SET clause... `SET column = wrong_value`, though this type of problem usually results in the values of the row in the wrong column, not a value in the wrong row.

I'd suggest looking for common, repeated values in the rows... that would indicate that an UPDATE statement updated more than one row.

Another possibility is something wrong in a trigger that is getting fired.

If you have multiple databases, and multiple connection pools, is your code getting the right connection. (Perhaps, everything about the UPDATE statement was right, but it was executed against the wrong database.... this is usually more of a problem with dev/test/prod database.)

For debugging this, the normative practice is to enable the MySQL log, and/or including instrumentation in the application to log the text of all SQL statements, just prior to execution.

A more intensive debugging would be to implement an AFTER INSERT trigger on the table, to capture the `OLD.` and `NEW.` values of all columns, and log those to another audit table.

Then again, there might not be anything wrong with the SQL, it might be the wrong variables (or values from a different session?) getting bound to the SQL statements.

The SQL causing the issue might be manually run, not executed as part of the application.  (Normally, this is where we tend to see missing or wrong predicates, which update every row in the table.)

These are only some pointers; no one is going to be able to debug your problem without looking at the code, and the test cases.

Comment: Thank you so much for a very detailed answer! This helped me eliminate different things that it could be. Anyone in this situation should try these things. For me it turned out to be an error while moving old posts to the new database. It connected to the wrong index ID's, so the moving script inserted the wrong message. I'd rate your comment up but I don't have enough reputation at the moment.